# Responding to mouse cursor position in a Windows 8.1 app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, windows

I have a Windows 8 application, and I need to detect when the mouse is at the bottom of the screen because my application has a CommandBar, and I would like to open it when the mouse is at the bottom. I already have swipe gestures that will open it when the user swipes, but now I have an added requirement for when the user does not have a touch device and instead must bring the mouse to the bottom of the screen to show my CommandBar. I am used to WPF's style of MouseMoved events, but unfortunately these are not available in Metro applications, so how can I get the mouse position or at least detect that the user has brought the mouse to the bottom of the screen? I have tried searching about this, but I couldn't find anything...perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: FWIW the standard way of opening the command bar is with a right click, not by using the mouse position.

Comment: @chuex You wouldn't believe how many people find that too complicated and then give your application a horrible rating because of it on the Store.

Comment: It is called PointerMoved in WinRT, it is available.

Comment: Its strange with RT, you need to get a PointerPoint object from the event arguments (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointermoved) and then from that, you can use either use PointerPoint.Position or transform it to a screen point (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.input.pointerpoint.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1). Example code in both references show this.

Comment: @HansPassant By the way, Hans, I did eventually figure out how to get the actual core speeds of a CPU (with clock-varying technologies like Turbo Boost): http://www.dima.to/blog/?p=101

Answer (score 0):

As Chue X said the standard way to open the app bar by mouse is right click.

Windows Runtime apps use Pointer messages for all pointer input: Mouse, touch and pen will all generate PointerPressed, PointerMoved, etc. You can examine the Pointer event args to see which type of input it is in the PointerPoint.PointerDevice.PointerDeviceType.

There are slightly different versions of the Pointer events on the CoreWindow (with full window scope) and on the xaml UIElement (scoped to the element). You can use either in a xaml app. For your use either would work. They give essentially the same information.

Responding to mouse interactions (XAML) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh994936.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I used to achieve this behavior from any OnPointerMoved event handler:

```
... OnPointerMoved(PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PointerPoint point = e.GetCurrentPoint(page);
    if (point.Position.Y > page.RenderSize.Height - 5)
    {
        page.MainMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```